# iOS backup error

Tags: iphone, ios, backup

I have problem to backup my iPhone (both to iCloud even to Computer).

iTunes only says: 'iTunes could not back up the iPhone because an error occured' and backup is terminated.

In iPhone's log I see this record:

```
Nov 12 12:10:14 iPhone BackupAgent2[16961] <Warning>: ERROR: Backup error - fcntl error: No space left on device (28) at path "/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/847C7E3F-CF06-40CC-A2D0-6CE43E5F72A4/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents/Documents" (MBErrorDomain/101)
```

So I think the problem is caused by application with ID 847C7E3F-CF06-40CC-A2D0-6CE43E5F72A4. Is there any way how to identify the application so I can delete it?

iOS 8.1; more than 3GB free; no jailbreak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd post this as a comment if I had enough reputation. I would search your logs for other instances of that UUID (847C7E3F-CF06-40CC-A2D0-6CE43E5F72A4) to see if there are more hints about what application is.

Note that the "no space left on device" is actually a ENOSPC error; it's trying to tell you that the path is too long. It appears that the application causing the problem has made a symbolic link referring to itself or a parent directory, and the iOS backup daemon naively follows that symbolic link repeatedly until the kernel rejects the clearly invalid path.

Comment: Thanks, your hint helped. I started applications one at a time until a saw UUID in logs and identified the app (iFiles).